# Integrating Cucumber into a test framework?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, frameworks, cucumber

I have written a Test framework (that supports Selenuim).
The way it works is such that when I create a test I only have to extend the base class..

```
 class NewTest extend BaseTest {

    @Test
    public ABC() {
      this.sel.driver.  ....
    }
 }
```

My question is how to integrate Cucumber into my framework, where the Framework is the provider of the Selenium driver, db connections,screenshots, ...etc

The idea is to make it in a way that it does not interfere with the Cucumber normal flow of programming.

Also I'm using maven and junit.

Answer (score 0):

@Test is for `Junit` not for `cucumber`.

Cucumber using gherkin language

You can check the setup and usage of cucumber from below tutorial

https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber-tutorial/

> My question is how to integrate Cucumber into my framework, where the
>   Framework is the provider of the Selenium driver, db
>   connections,screenshots, ...etc

Just create an package and add your classes like db, selenium etc into it, call them in script as we did in normal framework.

Note that cucumber just provide a flow to run the project from feature and using hook. so learn and did poc in cucumber and you will understand where you need to call what.